# What is the best way of scrolling the browser window for expanding elements?

Tags: javascript, window, scroll

What I want to do is scroll down the window when I expand elements in my page.

The effect I am trying to achieve is like the Stack Overflow comments. If it expands beyond the page, it scrolls down to fit all the comments in the window.

What is the best way of doing this?

Edit: I am using JQuery.

Comment: Are you using any specific javascript library?

Comment: Those with Safari may enjoy this:  http://www.gesteves.com/experiments/starwars.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery plugin worked well for me:
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the advantage of using Prototype, you can use `$(element).scrollTo()`.

Otherwise, the general idea is to calculate the cumulative offset of the element, then set `window.scrollTop` (and `window.scrollLeft`) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it nicely with [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) (built on top of [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org)):

```
new Effect.ScrollTo('someDiv',{...some parameters...})
```

It gives you finer control than Prototype alone (delay before start, duration and callback events (such as afterFinish) that allow you to trigger other effects or whatever you choose. You can make it scroll smoothly and nicely, so the page doesn't suddenly jump.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the next element in the source is you could actually just jump to that element (location.href="#..."). This would use the browser's native 'scrolling' and not use any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code wich is okay but not perfect. 
Based on the suggestion by blonkm

```
function scrollTo( Selector ){
  $(Selector).before("<a name='scroll' id='scroll'></a>");
  document.location.hash = 'scroll';
  $('scroll').remove();
}
```

This should work.
Requires jQuery but you already say your using that.